# Java cannot find ResteasyClient despite everything accounted for in pom

Tags: java, rest, maven

In my prototype projects, I work on implementing very simple REST service - both server (backend) and client that in fact is server too (frontend). Backend server works fine, but with client I encountered very, very strange problem. In Eclipse I have project "frontend" that has this bean called FrontEndPageBean.java:

```
package org.mader.demo.frontend;

import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

/** Bean to show off frontend handling of REST. */
@ManagedBean
public class FrontEndPageBean
{
  /**
   * Resolve data from backend through REST service.
   * @return Data as text.
   */
  public String getRestData()
  { // Retrieve RESTful service using client API from JAX-RS 2.0

    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://127.0.0.1:8080/backend/rest/data/1");

    Response response = target.request().get();
    // Read output in string format
    String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(value);
    response.close();

    return value;
  }
}
```

It is called in home.xhtml like that:

```
Text resolved by REST from backend: #{frontEndPageBean.restData}
```

This is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.mader.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Frontend App</name>
  <description>Demonstration Frontend App.</description>

  <properties>
    <webapp.directory>src/main/webapp</webapp.directory>
    <jboss.home>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</jboss.home>

    <!-- plugin versions -->
    <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>

    <!-- other -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>JBOSS_NEXUS</id>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency> <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill of Materials (BOM). -->
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Standard libraries. -->
    <dependency> <!-- CDI API -->
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Common Annotations API (JSR-250) -->
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- RESTeasy -->
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- JSF -->
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin> <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Problem is that Eclipse does not recognize **ResteasyClientBuilder**, **ResteasyClient** nor **ResteasyWebTarget**. In tooltip it reads "ResteasyClient cannot be resolved to a type". No import options visible. It does not compile. It Just Does Not Work(TM).

According to various pages about consuming REST, ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build(); is kosher way. Only thing that I can think up is that there is something to add to POM, some missing dependency. Visit to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec/jboss-javaee-all-7.0/1.0.0.Final does not help much, nor checking code of ResteasyClient - it looks like it should be already covered. Surely I missed something...

Environment: Java 1.7, Eclipse Kepler, Wildfly 8.0

Comment: you haven't included anything but the JAX-RS api jar, you need the RestEasy jar with the classes that are missing. search.maven.org will help you.

Comment: Well, I thought org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api did that. Looks like it is not enough.

Comment: that should say RestEasy **jars**, as you are missing multiple ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, entries in POM were missing.

I needed to add other entries like that:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note fully specified version and scope still being "provided".

I lost a lot of time chasing shadows. Lack of directly specified org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client etc in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec/jboss-javaee-7.0/1.0.0.Final was surefire way to put me on wrong track.